# How to save video with opencv python that can be played in browser

Tags: python, opencv

I am using Windows & Anaconda. This is my code to create video from images using opencv

`out = cv2.VideoWriter('video.mp4',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), fps, size)`

I also tried
`out = cv2.VideoWriter('video.mp4',cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'H264'), fps, size)` (this one gives an error)

This saves the video, I can play it in windows. But browser cannot play it. I assume, it was something to do with the codec, can someone help me here? I tried almost everything

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats any help from this link ?

Comment: It only shows videos with V80,V90 or H264 codec encoding, and i am asking how to do that :( How to change the encoding of CV2

Comment: what's the error you are getting ? and which version of opencv you are using ?